# Adding rows in Google sheet to create a chart

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a Pie chart using Google sheet data such as this:

| Vendor | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| Airbnb | $500 |
| Airbnb | $200 |
| Airbnb | $100 |
| McDonalds | $ 15 |
| McDonalds | $ 13 |
| Uber | $ 25 |
| Uber | $ 30 |

I want a PIE chart that shows 3 values, Airbnb, McDonalds, and Uber, and adds the values of each of the Airbnb, McDonalds, and Uber.

For instance, in the PIE chart, it would show:

| Vendor | Total | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Airbnb | $800 | 90% |
| McDonalds | $30 | 3% |
| Uber | $55 | 6% |

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a PIE chart of the second data set, transform your original data to match and then build the PIE chart from that.

#### QUERY Formula to Transform

```
=QUERY(A2:B8, "select A, SUM(B), SUM(B)/"&SUM(B2:B8)&" 
    group by A Label A '', SUM(B) '', SUM(B)/"&SUM(B2:B8)&" ''")
```

[image]